# Problems in launching matlab

Tags: matlab

Hi I'm quite new in ubuntu so forgive me if it is a stupid question.
I've tried to install matlab and have followed step by step all passages written in this link

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-matlab-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

I've encountered problem immediately after the screen with the sentence "all done"

I clicked the button finish because otherwise i couldn't write any more command and then have written these:

$ sudo wget -qO /usr/share/icons/matlab.png goo.gl/NDyi9t 
$ sudo wget -qO /usr/share/applications/matlab.desktop goo.gl/NaHXrn

but it doesn't seem to do anything, I mean sure it creates an icon with the image of matlab but if I click on it it does nothing, even if I wait. How can I do?

thank you for your time

Comment: What happens if you try to run `matlab` or `matlab -desktop` from a terminal?

Comment: thank you so much, it works! Now also if I click on the icon. The problem was with my license and it didn't tel me anything if i clicked on the icon. Doing from the terminal showed me the problem and fixed it